# detect the touch on UIView and transfer to UICollectionViewCell where it is

Tags: ios, iphone

I put one UIView on UICollectionViewCell

```
//UIView
@implementation MyUIView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *nibView =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyUIView"owner:self options:nil];
        UIView *bw = [nibView objectAtIndex:0] ;

        [self.contentView addSubview:bw];

    }
    return self;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if ( indexPath.section==0{
        IndexTodayTopicCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyUIView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.actionTarget = self;
        cell.topicDict = _topicDict;

        return cell;

    }
 }
```

but this will cause the UIView over the UICollectionViewCell

if I touch the UIView, the function didSelectItemAtIndexPath will not be triggered

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (0 == indexPath.section) { 

        [self.navigationController pushViewControllerSmoothly:SomeController navigationBarHidden:YES];
        }

 }
```

Your comment welcome

Comment: Why not set the view's `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling userInteraction for that view

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{

   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {
     NSArray *nibView =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyUIView"owner:self options:nil];
     UIView *bw = [nibView objectAtIndex:0] ;
     bw.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self.contentView addSubview:bw];

}
   return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I know above solution works perfect..but just putting the another way in which you can manually call UICollectionView delegate method on **ViewClicked** event

```
- (void)viewClicked:(UIView *)sender {

UICollectionView *collectionView;
UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell*)sender.superview.superview; //Since you are adding to cell.contentView, navigate two levels to get cell object
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];

[[collectionView delegate] collectionView:collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]; }
```